# При перемещении объекта начальное изображение остаётся на месте, но создаётся новое в указанных координатах

Tags: python, pygame

Пишу на питоне, изучаю pygame. Если я указываю новые координаты для объекта, в указанном месте создаётся новое изображение, но старое никуда не девается. Помогите пожалуйста

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
pygame.display.set_caption("Chess")
screen.fill((56, 122, 38))
icon = pygame.image.load("Icons/Chess_icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
white_field = pygame.image.load("Icons/white_field.png")

white_pawn1_coordinate_x = 200                                                          
white_pawn1_coordinate_y = 800

white_pawn1 = pygame.image.load("Icons/white_pawn.png")
white_figures.append(white_pawn1)                                                           

# Отображение поля

screen.blit(white_field, (0, 0))
screen.blit(white_field, (250, 0))
screen.blit(white_field, (500, 0))
screen.blit(white_field, (750, 0))
screen.blit(white_field, (125, 125))
screen.blit(white_field, (375, 125))
screen.blit(white_field, (625, 125))
screen.blit(white_field, (875, 125))
screen.blit(white_field, (0, 250))
screen.blit(white_field, (250, 250))
screen.blit(white_field, (500, 250))
screen.blit(white_field, (750, 250))
screen.blit(white_field, (125, 375))
screen.blit(white_field, (375, 375))
screen.blit(white_field, (625, 375))
screen.blit(white_field, (875, 375))
screen.blit(white_field, (0, 500))
screen.blit(white_field, (250, 500))
screen.blit(white_field, (500, 500))
screen.blit(white_field, (750, 500))
screen.blit(white_field, (125, 625))
screen.blit(white_field, (375, 625))
screen.blit(white_field, (625, 625))
screen.blit(white_field, (875, 625))
screen.blit(white_field, (0, 750))
screen.blit(white_field, (250, 750))
screen.blit(white_field, (500, 750))
screen.blit(white_field, (750, 750))
screen.blit(white_field, (125, 875))
screen.blit(white_field, (375, 875))
screen.blit(white_field, (625, 875))
screen.blit(white_field, (875, 875))

running = True
while running:

screen.blit(white_pawn1, (white_pawn1_coordinate_x, white_pawn1_coordinate_y))

pygame.display.update()

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        white_pawn1_coordinate_y -= 100
```

Comment: Используйте `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))` перед отрисовкой для отчистки экрана (Если у вас отображаются и другие объекты то их тоже нужно перерисовывать).

Comment: Спасибо огромное